# Which Lang is the fastet for working with xlsx-Files

Tags: excel, powershell, user-interface, programming-languages

i have an xlsx file with some sheets. What I want to do, is to Programming a small GUI that read out 150 Cells show the user up to 50 inputboxes and take the inputboxes-Value into an other sheet.

Is there an other programming language to do that job faster?

Here My read out CODE:

```
 function Create_Proj_obj
    {
    return [pscustomobject] @{
        'SPNum' = [STRING]""
        'Num' = [STRING]""
        'User' = [STRING]""
        'Project' = [STRING]""  
    }


    }

    #Program definieren
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
    #Datei Definieren
    #$Pfad = 'H:\temp\AZN.xlsx'
    #password auslesen
    #$PW = Get-Content 'H:\AZN\AZN.pw'
    #im hintergrund ausführen
    $excel.visible = $false
    #Datei öffnen
    $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($Pfad,3,0,5,$PW,$PW)
    $tabelle= $workbook.Worksheets.Item('Proj_overview')
    #Worksheets.Item(1).Range("A1", "C3") | foreach { $_.Text}
    $range = @()
    $range = $tabelle.Range('C4:AZ6')|foreach { $_.Text}
    #Write-Host $range | ft

    for( $sp=0;$sp -le 49; $sp++){
        
        #Alte Daten ablöschen
        $ProjData= Create_Proj_obj
        # Felder auslesen
        $ProjData.SPNum = $sp
        $ProjData.Num = $range[$sp]
        $ProjData.User  = $range[$sp+50]
        $ProjData.Project = $range[$sp+100]
 
        IF ($ProjData.Num-ne "" -or $ProjData.User -ne "" -or $ProjData.Project -ne "" )
            {
                $ProjList.Add($ProjData)
                Write-Host $ProjList
            }
        }
        #write-host $ProjData|ft
    $excel.Quit()
```

For now i have realised that with Powershell and a the ComObject of excel.
I also tried the importExcel modul, but have not really a Time saving.

The Program needs nearly 2 seconds to show die GUI.

Comment: The Interop library is very slow.  Fastest method is just getting values (no formatting) is to use OleDb.

Comment: Export the .xlsx file worksheets to plain-text .csv files. Easy to do with `ImportExcel` module or VBS. Read with `Import-Csv`. Fast.

Comment: Import-Excel is same slowly like the Com-Object. The OleDb is very fast but the file is unforinelly Password-protectet... any Ideas else?